# Docker Compose running but nothing showing up in browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have build a django application and containerized using Docker. It was working perfectly, but after adding docker-compose the compose build and run the container successfully but the browser is not showing up the app running.

```
$ docker-compose ps
          Name                         Command               State                    Ports                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pan-card-ocr-master_web_1   python3 manage.py runserve ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp,:::8000->8000/tcp
```

Docker logs:

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
pcard.FileUploadModel: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the PcardConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
pcard.ImageUploadModel: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the PcardConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
September 28, 2021 - 05:20:17
Django version 3.2.7, using settings 'pancard.settings'
Starting development server at http://localhost:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
   web:
       build: .
       command: python3 manage.py runserver localhost:8000
       ports:
           - 8000:8000
```

Dockerfile:

```
# pull the official base image
FROM ubuntu:latest
# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libpoppler-cpp-dev pkg-config python-dev mupdf

RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y

RUN apt-get install -y default-jre
RUN apt-get install -y default-jdk


RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
#RUN pip3 install virtualenv
#RUN python3 -m virtualenv env
#RUN source env/bin/activate
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
# 
# Command line to activate docker
# docker build --tag django_demo:latest .
# docker run --name django_demo -d -p 8000:8000 django_demo:latest
```

After going to localhost:8000:

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Docker versions:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
```

Comment: did you try with `command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`? In Docker-compose.yaml

Comment: Thanks bro. Works now. If you don't mind can you explain why 0.0.0.0 works and localhost doesn't?

Comment: When you write `localhost:8080`, this means the app is only accessible from the same computer so you can connect your django app inside of the container. However, when you write `0.0.0.0` all ip address can access your app.